# Automated Notification possible?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a party planner application.  I'd like to send a reminder to users (who are in a certain party_id group) that their party is starting tonight

For example I'd like to send this message to everyone in the group:
"Hey don't forget about the party at Paul's house tonight at 9PM!"

What is the best way to send out reminders to users when a party is going to start?  This would be done in an automated fashion, server running a cron job ever so often checking for new reminders to send out

Comment: do you have the time\date and details stored?

Comment: Yes, the server will know when to send the message.  I was just curious as to if facebook allowed bulk messenging of app users

Comment: Why don't you directly ask? "Mass mailing with Facebook - how?"

Comment: I didnt ask directly because I wasnt asking how to mass email, was looking for somehting inside FB eco-system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I would do two types of notifications:

- First and most obvious is sending an email to the users.
- Second would
  be to send the user a Facebook application request.

The apprequest will show a notification next to your application name and it will also show on the top navigation panel as a notification from your application. Once the user click on that notification and comes to your application, you will have to read the notifications that user has and properly determine what to show them and then delete the notification.

Check out : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels

```
<?php 

  $app_id = YOUR_APP_ID;
  $app_secret = YOUR_APP_SECRET;

  $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
    "client_id=" . $app_id .
    "&client_secret=" . $app_secret .
    "&grant_type=client_credentials";

  $app_access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

  $user_id = THE_CURRENT_USER_ID;

  $apprequest_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/" .
    $user_id .
    "/apprequests?message='INSERT_UT8_STRING_MSG'" . 
    "&data='INSERT_STRING_DATA'&"  .   
    $app_access_token . "&method=post";

  $result = file_get_contents($apprequest_url);
  echo("App Request sent?", $result);
?>
```

Comment: Ya email is most obvious and easiest, was hoping for something inside FB like your app request idea.  Does FB limit how much you send out requests?  Like if there is some crazy office party with 250 people signed up, are we allowed to loop over that and send out mass requests?  Or say there are 1000 parties across the country each with 30 people in the party starting at 10PM, 30k request loop...?  (I realize chances of app being that popular are low :-)

Comment: I never ran to any limitations, and my loops iterated around 10,000 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a php file using a cron job, just have the php file do your normal work of extracting the information from the database and I'd suggest using [Pear Mail](http://tuxradar.com/practicalphp/15/5/2) to mail it out.

You can't really send out mass messages on Facebook, they mark it as spam. There isn't a set number, it's usually around 10. A better solution is just to email the reminder to them, or perhaps get their cell phone number and send them a text, if you have the resources.

[Here's a good explanation of how to run a PHP file using a Cron Job](http://support.modwest.com/content/5/125/en/can-i-run-a-php-script-on-cron.html)